# Why does output behave differently over ssh?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I execute a function foo.sh (which does some more complex things like executing multiple python processes) over SSH in two different ways.

First, the following way (interactive shell):

```
ssh me@server
./foo.sh
```

This way I get all the output (stderr and stdout) of foo.sh

Then, the other way:

```
ssh me@server "./foo.sh"
```

This way I don't get any output from any of the subprocesses. What is the difference between the two methods? Why does stderr/stdout behave differently?

An example for foo.sh is

```
#! /bin/bash
./bar.py
```

Where bar.py is

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
from sys import stdout, stderr
from time import sleep

while True:
   stdout.write("A\n")
   stderr.write("B\n")
   sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Please provide some minimal contents for `foo.sh` to reproduce the behavior you observe.

Comment: What is the first method? You run the script in an interactive shell after logging into the remote server?

Comment: Yeah the first method is using an interactive shell

Comment: @merlin2011 i added a minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to force pseudo TTY allocation:

```
ssh -t me@server "./foo.sh"
```

While doing `ssh remote "somecommand"`, you are spawning an non-login, non-interactive shell session on the remote host that is not bound to any terminal, so no job control. Thats why you just need to force a pseudo TTY allocation.